# Make always relinks

Tags: makefile

I have a make file as follows - based on the variable type - I have to build either an exe or lib - the following make file works fine - but it all the time links even though there is no change in the code.

---

```
CC:=gcc

CFLAGS:= -fPIC -Wall

BIN_NAME := test

type :=exe

$(BIN_NAME): $(type)_${BIN_NAME}

file.o: file.c

        @echo "Compiling ..."   

        $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $<

lib_$(BIN_NAME): file.o

        @echo "Creating Lib ..."    

        $(CC) -shared -o $(BIN_NAME).so file.o

exe_$(BIN_NAME): file.o

        @echo "Linking ..." 
        $(CC) -o $(BIN_NAME) file.o

all: $(BIN_NAME)

.DEFAULT_GOAL := all

.PHONY: clean

clean:

        rm -f *.o
```

---

`make -d` ends some thing like below

```
Prerequisite `file.c' is older than target `file.o'.
No need to remake target `file.o'.
Finished prerequisites of target file `exe_test'.
Must remake target `exe_test'.
Putting child 0x00b12e50 (exe_test) PID 33137 on the chain.
Live child 0x00b12e50 (exe_test) PID 33137 
Linking ...
```

Not sure how to avoid the re-linking - any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your target has a different name than the file it generates. make looks compares the timestamp of the file with the same name as the target (in your case, exe_test) and compares it to the timestamps of the prerequisites; if the file doesn't exist, it is always built.

But your instructions create a file called test, not exe_test, so it will never find exe_test and always rebuild.

Comment: This is [Rule 2](http://make.mad-scientist.net/papers/rules-of-makefiles/#rule2) of the GNU make maintainer's "Rules of Makefiles" for a reason.